# Android - MediaPlayer HTTP Error Handling

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am attempting to create an Android app which collects a variety of remote song links and plays them out for users. The app uses Android's MediaPlayer, and every single song link redirects to a Stream URL which the MediaPlayer handles and eventually plays out.

However, some of these song links actually redirect and provide a **HTTP 404 Error** as they are not available, and I want to know if there is any way to directly handle/catch for these HTTP errors instantly. As of now, what the MediaPlayer does is signal out a:

`error (1, -2147483648)`

... after it attempts to connect with the data source **10 times**, which I can then catch to notify the user that the song is unavailable.

Of course though, having the user wait for 10 retries takes far too much time, and so I want to know if there is a way to catch the very first moment the HTTP error occurs from the MediaPlayer without having to check the URL before sending it to the MediaPlayer, or having to hack away and manage the exceptions with a network proxy connected to the MediaPlayer.

**Exception given by MediaPlayer 10 times:**

`07-16 05:16:30.549: E/MediaHTTPConnection(16698): IOException: java.io.IOException: Http Response: 404`

Comment: Do this list of 10 exceptions are only visible in a logcat but app receives just one exception in MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener callback? Or do all of them are delivered to an error listener?

Comment: These list of 10 exceptions are only visible in Logcat, and the app itself is only notified of the 10th (the last) exception through MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.

Answer (score 0):

If the error pops up 10 times, and each time an error is put out, then I don't see why a simple try-catch loop will not work:

```
try {
    // download URL
} catch (IOException e) {
    // presumably an exception is thrown the first time it gets 404 so put the error handling code here
}
```

Also, might I suggest using multithreading to download from URLs using something like the `ExectutorService` which allows you to submit `Runnable` classes to it and run them concurrently (i.e. the download Tasks for each video so they download at the same time)

Comment: The exceptions as shown from the Logcat come from MediaHTTPConnection which works underneath Android's MediaPlayer framework. Only the 10th exception pops up as a callback from MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener which I can then use to notify the user that the song is not available.